# AJAX Crawling with question mark instead of hashbang

Tags: ajax, seo, web-crawler, hashbang

**Where I'm at:** I've read Google's documentation regarding it's AJAX crawling, and I've searched around a bit in this website and others, but I'm quite confused, as it seems that all problems address the same issue: AJAX crawing with hashbangs?
I've developed an app which, among other purposes, let's the user search for locations worldwide, using an AJAX searcher quite similar to Google's, but my app uses exclusively the question mark in AJAX, instead of hashbang. Due to compatibility issues, changing it to the hashbang is not an option.

Not only am I largely confused by the fact that I could not find anyone else using the question mark instead of the hashbang, I'm also wondering if there is any documentation regarding **my issue**: how to let google bot crawl all my AJAX content when I'm using the **question mark instead of a hashbang** in my AJAX app.

Answer (score 1):

The [AJAX crawling schema](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) was created explicitly for applications and websites using hashbang (`#!`) in the URL structure, because the fragment part of the URLs only exist on the client side; the URL rewriting in the specs, i.e. from `#!` to `?_escaped_fragment_=` is meant to solve that.

Since most of the web is already making use of Javascript in a way or other, we (Google) needed a better solution, so we started executing Javascript in the pages we crawled and effectively render every page, just like a normal browser would. To quote our blogpost, [Understanding web pages better](http://www.googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html):

> In order to solve this problem, we decided to try to understand pages by executing JavaScript. It’s hard to do that at the scale of the current web, but we decided that it’s worth it. We have been gradually improving how we do this for some time. In the past few months, our indexing system has been rendering a substantial number of web pages more like an average user’s browser with JavaScript turned on.

You can also see what we "see" using Fetch as Google in Search Console (former Webmaster Tools); read more about the feature in our post titled [Rendering pages with Fetch as Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2014/05/rendering-pages-with-fetch-as-google.html)

Before you do anything else, please try to fetch a few pages from your site with Fetch as Google. You might not have to do anything at all, it might actually work out of the box. And the good news is that it's not only Google that's rendering pages!

Comment: Okay so this wasn't exactly the answer I was looking for, but it pushed me in the right direction. I changed the POST method so that it's converted to a GET, and now it's usable.

Now, the question is, how do I get google to look at my website each time a user is looking for a location.eg:
www.mywebpage.com/search?city=HERECOMESTHEQUERY
How do I get Google to look for the value of the parameter of "city" so that it crawls the results?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Craphter search results and other auto-generated pages are not quite what we want in our index. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769 for more (search for "Use robots.txt to prevent crawling of search results pages"). Ignoring that for now, you want to generate a sitemap (xml) somehow, and then either put that in your robots.txt file, or submit it in Search Console.

Comment: Hey @methode, thank you very much for your time. Now, it's not quite clear to me what to do, here's my situation: I've got over 5 thousand possible search results, let's say they're places around the world. Now, are you suggesting that we include our 5k results in our sitemap? Because that's what's worrying us. If that's not an option, then can we input all our search results into a special webpage and upload it to our server so that it's indexed, or will that result in a penalization? It's quite a shame that we can't index so much helpful content, that users will really search for and like.

Comment: Yeah, I sitemap would help us discover the content and potentially index it. Also, we don't penalise that easily :) worst case the urls won't have much visibility.

Comment: Right, so is there any chance to be penalized by Google if we list the 5000 places in a web page, which will also describe to the user the web site?

Comment: No, but we only look at about 1000 links on a page and drop the rest.

Comment: Okay, but they aren't links at all, it's simply a list of the 5000 geographical places which the app works with.

Comment: I don't understand why would you do that. If you throw at me a blob of 5000 locations, what am i supposed to do with it if they're not even links? Anyway, in general we don't penalise for stuff like that.

Comment: It's useful for the user which searches that specific place finds it in our site.

Comment: OK, we'll agree to disagree.